# Opel Corsa D cannot idle on start and dies instantly

Tags: stall, fuel-injection, opel, corsa

I have an 16 year old Opel Corsa D 1.2 80HP ECOTEC and i stopped at a traffic light and after i went in neutral my car couldnt idle and the motor died. It actually stuttered for half a second around 500-600 rpm and then shut off. After that i power it up and imediattely  goes under 600 rpm and dies while trying to idle. I couldnt make it idle for more than 5-6 seconds. I get the usual stalling lights - battery and oil red lights

What i tried and tested:

- Tried to keep it revved at around 2000 rpm for 1-2 minutes but after i get my foot off the gas it goes slowly to 500-600 rpm then dies
- Checked my oil level and battery voltage, which are fine
- Made sure i refilled with petrol not diesel

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you refill with petrol just before this started happening? If so, you could have water in the fuel.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @MTA i did 2 days ago and travelled about 40-50 kilometers since then

Comment: Two days and 40-50 km makes it much less likely to be water, but still possible. I have seen cars disabled by water in fuel after filling up, but they have traveled less than 1 km before stalling. If you can take a fuel sample from the engine compartment into a clear glass bottle, look for a layer of water in the bottom of the bottle.

Comment: Does it still start the die? Could be numerous things, fuel starvation, crank sensor, coil pack, slipped timing, so many possibilities.